# Drawback of using Schottky Diode to lower MOSFET threshold voltage?

Tags: mosfet, ldo, pmos, schottky

I am considering using Schottky diode to lower PMOS's Vth as the following diagram:
[image]

As the current extracted from Schottky diode is small enough to provide 0.3-0.4V voltage drop, PMOS's threshold voltage will decrease due to body effect. Thus, PMOS only requires small vgs to be turned on.

However, some people say this method is impractical or rare to see in low voltage IC design. I would like to know if there is any drawback when we use it in LDO. Thanks!

Comment: XY problem. Why do you need lower Vgsth in the first place?

Comment: To lower the source voltage of PMOS

Comment: *To lower the source voltage of PMOS* Why is that needed? You basically have a PMOS diode which cannot drop less voltage than Vt. **There is no way around that.** If you want to drop a smaller voltage you must use a different component (like a diode or a resistor) or make a circuit to do the function.

Comment: That’s not a goal in itself! Explain why you need it

Comment: Sorry for posting wrong figure. Actually I am designing the buffer stage of LDO.  I just want to lower vgs so the output level can be low enough to drive pass transistor.

Comment: It is possible to lower the threshold voltage with a body bias, but it is tricky. You don't explain how you actually intend to construct this circuit. If with discrete components, what 4-terminal PMOS will you use? If as a custom IC, can you actually make a good Schottky diode?

Answer (score 3):

This cannot work. It is not possible to **lower** the threshold voltage. The threshold voltage can only be **increased** by having a voltage between backgate (bulk) and source. See the [relevant article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage).

If there was some way to lower the threshold voltage of a MOSFET through a "circuit trick" then for sure I would know and use that trick. I've been dealing with CMOS circuits for more than 25 years.

The only way to lower the threshold voltage is to change the physical properties of the MOSFET (doping, oxide thickness etc.).

Comment: I bet the integrated LDO ICs achieve their low dropout by having specially doped/designed integrated PMOS pass elements for the integrated op-amp to control. I expect their internal PMOST FET's Vgs must be at least, or slightly less than,  the specified drop-out voltage, in order to operate and keep regulation.

Comment: @KyranF No that is not the case. "specially doped" means: extra process step, extra mask(s) which equals **more expensive**. Also, it is simply **not needed**. For an LDO a "normal Vt" transistor can be used. A low Vt device would make sense for a regulator with a common drain output stage but that will never achieve the same low drop voltage as an LDO. I suggest that you study LDO designs to learn how that works, start here: https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/landing-pages/001/fundamentals-of-ldo-design-and-applications.html

Comment: Thanks for the info and link! :)

Comment: But why can we use “forward body bias” technique to turn on MOSFET at lower gate voltage?

Comment: *But why can we use “forward body bias” to turn on MOSFET at lower gate voltage?* Not sure what you mean or how that would work, show an example of such a circuit. Note that "lower gate voltage" says **nothing** about Vgs. Suppose I have an NMOS and I make Vsource = -1 V and Vgate = 0 V (so Vgs = 1 V) then this NMOS conducts while Vgate = 0 V. Does that mean that the threshold voltage of this NMOS has become smaller?

Comment: Sorry for not writing clearly. I just read it on this website
https://semiengineering.com/body-bias-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-care/
According to their figure, when lowering body voltage and keeping source voltage constant, we can lower MOSFET's threshold voltage. This is called forward body bias.
There are also some papers regarding this technique, so I am not sure if I misunderstood it or not...

Comment: @dinex I cannot make heads or tails from that article. In **my opinion**: the author has **no clue** what he's writing about. Most of his article is "general observations" (example: *the use of integrated circuits (ICs) has exploded over the past decade.*) Didn't you notice that this has already been going on for the last 40 years?! There's no **schematic** in the article at all. I really think it would be wise to **ignore** this article. There might be a point in switching the connection of the backgate in certain situations but that isn't explained in this article.

Comment: There is another paper regarding this technique, although it does not call it forward body bias directly...
http://www.csie.ncue.edu.tw/csie/ic/Seminar_new/9701/971124/971124_01.pdf
In Figure 6, it also uses Schottky diode to control threshold voltage. That is why I am confused

Comment: @dinex That article is a lot better (from IEEE so must be). I think that under certain circumstances this might work. However, this isn't a trick you can or should use unless you have investigated its consequences. As said in the article, the way they bias the Bulk-Source diode of the PMOS means that a parasitic PNP transistor might be triggered. **This is something you must avoid**. Not all processes have the "heavily doped buried layer" so this trick can only be applied in specific CMOS processes. Also note that this article was published in 1998 and they're mentioning...

Comment: .. a 2um process which is **ancient** these days. On more modern processes I don't even expect this trick to help much. Probably the performance of the PMOS in the process they were using for the article's research was so poor that they needed tricks like this to get some decent performance. Things have moved on from then. We now have CMOS processes with much better transistors so we don't need tricks like proposed in the article. And again: the trick doesn't really lower the Vt, it just helps a bit to make the PMOS conduct better.

Comment: It is **possible** to lower a PMOS threshold voltage using body bias. I have done it using commercial CMOS processes. The fact that the references are old papers, or you don't think it will "help much", or you think some article is poorly written does not change that fact. The second sentence in your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Let's assume you're correct and I am not. Then can you explain why the formula for \$V_{TN}\$ on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage does not allow the case which you suggest where \$V_{TN} < V_{T0}\$ ? Perhaps that Body effect model is limited and not valid for the "threshold lowering" \$V_{SB}\$? Perhaps instead of "threshold lowering" this body bias is more of a "channel helping" effect, the channel becomes more conductive, the same could be achieved with a lower Vt.

Comment: No, that's not how this works. I don't have to explain everything, particularly on Wikipedia. You asserted that it was "impossible" to lower the MOSFET threshold voltage using the body bias...I just need to give a single counterexample. So, from "MOSFET design for forward body biasing scheme", IEEE Electron Device Letters, Vol. 27, #5 : "There are two options for body bias...: reverse bias to increase \$V_{TH}\$...and forward bias (\$V_F\$)  **to decrease \$V_{TH}\$** and increase device performance."

Comment: Or see "Adaptive Body Bias for Reducing Impacts of Die-to-Die and Within-Die Parameter Variations on Microprocessor Frequency and Leakage", IEEE JSSC, Vol. 37, #11. Or "Dynamic Threshold-Voltage MOSFET (DTMOS) for Ultra-Low Voltage VLSI", IEEE Trans. Electron Devices, Vol. 44, #3. All **peer reviewed** respected journals. Using FBB is a well-known technique for lowering the threshold voltage and improving the speed of digital circuits. And I've been doing CMOS design for over 40 years, as if that mattered.